# iTunes Keyboard Shortcut for exiting search function

Tags: macos, itunes, osx-mavericks

In iTunes on OS X, you can search for music in your library by using the `CMD+F` shortcut. However, as far as I can tell, there exists no shortcut for accessing those items once the search has completed. This isn't a huge problem, but it certainly would make searching faster if such a shortcut existed. Does anyone know if this exists? Thanks.

Edit: I should note that I use the "Songs" tab (as opposed to the Albums, Artists, Genres, etc. tabs).

Comment: What does `Esc` do? Which ones have you tried?

Comment: `Esc` just removes the search text. It doesn't actually remove focus from the search function. I've tried pretty much every shortcut I can think of. The only one that I've found that actually takes focus away from the search function is `CMD+L`, which focuses on the currently playing song; but, used in the search function, cancels the search results.